# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineHeight' of null

Tags: javascript, markdown, atom-editor

I got following error in Atom Markdown editor in the console whenever i click some word in Markdown file

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineHeight' of null marker-view.coffee:23
module.exports.MarkerView.appendRegion marker-view.coffee:23
MarkerView marker-view.coffee:15
module.exports.HighlightedAreaView.handleSelection highlighted-area-view.coffee:65
(anonymous function) highlighted-area-view.coffee:1
jQuery.event.dispatch /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:4676
elemData.handle /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:4360
jQuery.event.trigger /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:4594
(anonymous function) /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:5119
jQuery.extend.each /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:590
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:237
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/space-pen/vendor/jquery.js:5118
$.fn.trigger main.coffee:31
module.exports.React.createClass.componentDidUpdate /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/editor-component.js:269
mixInto.notifyAll /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactMountReady.js:69
ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.close /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactReconcileTransa…:87
Mixin.closeAll /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/Transaction.js:242
Mixin.perform /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/Transaction.js:175
ReactComponent.Mixin.performUpdateIfNecessary /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactComponent.js:478
ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactCompositeCompon…:1157
runBatchedUpdates /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactUpdates.js:66
(anonymous function) /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactUpdates.js:86
Mixin.closeAll /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/Transaction.js:242
Mixin.perform /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/Transaction.js:175
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactDefaultBatching…:70
batchedUpdates /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactUpdates.js:35
ReactEventEmitterMixin.handleTopLevel /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactEventEmitterMix…:53
handleTopLevelImpl /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactEventTopLevelCa…:81
(anonymous function) /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/react-atom-fork/lib/ReactEventTopLevelCa…:140
```

How do i fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a null reference error. You are calling lineHeight on an object that is null.

Comment: yes, but it is internal to atom editor. How do i fix it?

Comment: Just a guess, but I would check for other errors on the page. Look in the JS console. If it's internal it could be due to another failing piece of JavaScript code on the page

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Due to this bug, i could not use the atom editor itself.